# How to give textvalue and value property to combobox?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have one form in a Windows application as per below image:

[image: My Windowfrom]

I try to use this code to display text in comboBox in "Designer.cs":

```
this.cmbLanguage.FormattingEnabled = true;
this.cmbLanguage.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
    Language.LSelectLang.LANGUAGE_ENGLISH,               //"English",
    "Chinese_TC",
    "Chinese_SC",
    Language.LSelectLang.LANGUAGE_GERMAN,                //"German",
    Language.LSelectLang.LANGUAGE_FRENCH,                //"French",
    Language.LSelectLang.LANGUAGE_JAPANESE,              //"Japanese",
    Language.LSelectLang.LANGUAGE_SPANISH,               //"Spanish",
    Language.LSelectLang.LANGUAGE_HINDI});               //"Hindi"});
```

It's OK with it, but I want to also pass a value type to access specific text display in combo box.

So, how to pass that in my combo box?

Comment: What do you mean *value type to access specific text*?

Comment: just like dropdownlist property `text` and `value` property. i want this kind of property to define in my `combobox` to access `english` etc.. using `value` property. @CuongLe

Comment: How can do this? Have you any idea? @CuongLe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unluckily, Win Form does not define `ListItem` like Web, but you can define your own class, then override `ToString` method:

```
public class YourItem<T>
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text;
    }
}
```

Then you can use:

```
var item = new YourItem<string>() { 
             Text = "text", 
             Value = "value" 
       };

cmbLanguage.Items.Add(item);
```

To access value:

```
    var selectedItem = (YourItem<string>) cmbLanguage.SelectedItem;
    var value = selectedItem.Value;
```

Comment: Is it possible to do in `Designer.cs` file where i modify my current code ? @CuongLe

Comment: @smoothersillent: Should not touch on Designer.cs you can make it work on Load event

Comment: for every text which display in my combobox like `english,German` i write `var item = new ypuritem<string>()` @CuongLe

Comment: Ok..Now how can I access the selected Value from the combobox..can you please give an example...? @CuongLe